# Return specific user if uid option is present else return entire user list

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

i have the followiing code

```
async findAllUser(uid: number): Promise<User[]> {
    const users = await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('u')
      .where('u.id = :id', { id: uid })
      .leftJoinAndSelect('u.userRole', 'userRole')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('userRole.role', 'role')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('u.userAccess', 'userAccess')
      .leftJoinAndMapOne('u.profile', UserProfile, 'userProfile', 'userProfile.user_id=u.id')
      .getMany();
    return users;
  }
```

if uid is null then fetch all user record else if uid is present fetch only one user record
How to achieve by this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is dynamically add the `where` attribute to the query like so

```js
async findAll(uid: number): Promise<User[]> {
  const usersQuery = this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('u')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('u.userRole', 'userRole')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('userRole.role', 'role')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('u.userAccess', 'userAccess')
      .leftJoinAndMapOne('u.profile', UserProfile, 'userProfile', 'userProfile.user_id=u.id');
  if (uid) {
    usersQuery.where('u.id = :id', {id: uid});
  }
  return usersQuery.getMany();
}
```

Now if the `uid` is passed to the `findAll` function, the `where` condition will be set, otherwise with no `where` clause, the query will retrieve all users. Also, now you can just return the query with `.getMany()` and `node` will `await` the result for you so you return a promise.

Comment: It was so easy just basic javascript.Thanks it works!